# How to post Logger.log content into Spreadsheet cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that was provided by someone on here that is intended to be used to retrieve the URL of the latest file in a drive folder. However, the script only works up to having the link in the logger, and not actually posting it into a cell.

Therefore, how can I have it post to a spreadsheet? This is the script I got, and I actually want it to post the URL in Column5 based on a value of Column4. If Column4 value is "YES" the link will be posted but if it is "NO" in column4 the it will simply be empty.

```
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();
  var fileObj = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    fileObj.push({url: file.getUrl(), date: file.getDateCreated()});
  }
  fileObj.sort(function(a, b) {return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date)});
  return fileObj[0].url;
}

function myFunction() {
  var folderId = "###";
  var lastFileUrl = getLatestFile(folderId);
  Logger.log(lastFileUrl)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getLatestFile(folderId) {
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();
  var fileObj = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    fileObj.push({url: file.getUrl(), date: file.getDateCreated()});
  }
  fileObj.sort(function(a, b) {return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date)});
  return fileObj[0].url;
}

function putInSS(ssid,sheetname,folderId) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('sheetname');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var rg5=sh.getRange(1,5,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var v5=rg5.getValues();
  var v=rg.getValues();
  var url=getLastestFile(folderId);
  v.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(r[3]=='YES') {
      v5[i]=url;
    }
    if(r[3]=='NO') {
      v5[i]='';
    }
  });
  rg5.setValues(v5)
}

    enter code here
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the script but I'm getting a `Cannot convert Array to Numbers` error?

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: The line for `rg5.setValues(v5)`